# Angular PrimeNG: Column Selection

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng-datatable, primeng-table

I need to find a way to select individual columns in PrimeNG. Below is my environment / setup. I haven't found a way in the [PrimeNG Documentation](https://primeng.org/table) that supports column selection. There is one area called ["column selection"](https://primeng.org/table#column-selection) but it doesn't actually contain any code that enables column selection in the example.

**CONTEXT**

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.0",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "primeng": "^12.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I am using Angular 12.0 and PrimeNG 12.1.0.

**TABLE TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

interface Row {
  id?: number,
  name?: string,
  description?: string
}

interface Column {
  field: string,
  header: string
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

    RowData: Row[] = [];
    ColumnData: Column[] = [];
    constructor() {}
    //Table Population Data

    @Input() rowData: Row[];
    @Input() columnData: any[];

    selectedRow: Row;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ColumnData = this.columnData;
    this.RowData = this.rowData;
  }

  onRowSelect(event: Row) {
    console.log(event.id);
    console.log(event.name);
    console.log(event.description);
  }

  selectColumnHeader(checkValue: Column) {
    
    switch(checkValue.field) {
      
      case "id": {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.RowData.length; i++)
        {
          console.log(this.RowData[i].id);
        }

        break;
      }

      case "name": {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.RowData.length; i++)
        {
          console.log(this.RowData[i].name);
        }

        break;
    
      }

      case "description": {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.RowData.length; i++)
        {
          console.log(this.RowData[i].description);
        }

        break;
      }
    }

  }
```

**TABLE HTML:**

```
<p-table #myTable [value]="RowData" [columns] = "ColumnData"
         selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRow"
         dataKey="id" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect(selectedRow)">

    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of ColumnData"
            [pSortableColumn]="col.field">    
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon field="col.field"></p-sortIcon>  
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-RowData let-columns let-editing="editing">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="RowData">
            <td
                *ngFor="let col of ColumnData">
                {{RowData[col.field]}} 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Below this a test component which simply declares the data to be used in my table component.

**TEST TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { TableComponent } from '../table/table.component';


interface row {
  id?: number,
  name?: string,
  description?: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  myColumns = [{field: "id", header: "ID"}, 
               {field: "name", header: "Name"}, 
               {field: "description", header: "Description"}];
               
  myData: row[] = [{id: 0, name: "L", description: "Intern"},
                   {id: 1, name: "Test", description: "PrimeNG"},
                   {id: -1, name: "Jane Doe", description: "Hi"},
                   {id: 999999, name: "Big Num", description: "Almost 1 million"},
                   {id: 10000001, name: "Friend",description: "A friend"},
                   {id: 0.5, name: "T-swift", description: "Chief's fan!"}];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

**TEST HTML:**

```
<app-table
[columnData]="myColumns"
[rowData]="myData"
></app-table>
```

I have tried using `<p-tableCheckbox> and <p-tableHeaderCheckbox>` and hiding `<p-tableCheckbox>` but using `<p-tableHeaderCheckbox` selection simply selects all data because I was unable to find a way to link the `<p-tableCheckbox` to specific `<p-tableHeaderCheckbox>`.

Comment: There is a code section below the example :)

Comment: Can you point it out for me more specifically? The "Column Selection" example code is referring to adding those blue selection buttons, I believe, and not actually highlighting the column itself.

Comment: Well if you press the button it selects the column, even tho it's not highlighted